# Looping and updating multiple values of the same array in parallel?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, async-await

The array has like 100.000 elements.
And when I loop over it, I noticed that the page freezes for a short period of time.
I read that to avoid this I need to loop over chunks of the array inside a `setTimeout` call, to let the browser "breathe" in between these calls.

But what if I use promises instead of setTimeout and run them in parallel instead of one after the other? So each promise would loop over a portion of the array, and update it. Would this create unexpected issues, like the array not being updated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this if you're not using Web Workers:

(Basing my answer of of Jacob's)

```
async function workOnArray(array, sliceSize) {
   let promises = []

   let sliceCount = Math.ceil(array.length / sliceSize)

   for (let i = 0; i < sliceCount; i++) {
      promises.push(workOnSlice(array, i * sliceSize, sliceSize)
   }

   return Promise.all(promises)
}

async function workOnSlice(array, index, count) {
  for (let i = index; i < Math.min(index + count, array.length); i++) {
    doSomethingExpensive(array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, that won't work quite right. When you call `workOnSlice` it'll run that loop because nothing is being awaited, so essentially this is running all of the processing work synchronously.

Comment: But all the `workOnSlice` calls will be placed on the event loop, right? The `doSomethingExpensive` call will be done on each of elements in the slice synchronously

Comment: Async functions are synchronous until the first await is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you implement the Promises. Just be aware that if you're calling an async function, everything up to the point where you `await` is still synchronous code. So if you called `Promise.all` on a bunch of calls to this:

```
async function workOnSlice(array, index, count) {
  for (let i = index; i < index + count; i++) {
    doSomethingExpensive(array[i]);
  }
}
```

...it would still commandeer the CPU in the same way. Also, keep in mind that `Promise.all` doesn't actually run any code parallel; the only thing it does is allow async waits in parallel; once waits have completed, it's still a single JS thread that runs task code.

I'd recommend using a worker process/thread instead for *actual* parallel processing, if possible. Or if you don't care about parallel processing and just want to yield to the event loop periodically, you could queue the items to process and have a process/wait loop.

Comment: what if I wrap the content of that function in `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { .... })` ? will it still run in sync when called inside Promise.all() ?

Comment: Yes. The code in the `new Promise` body runs _synchronously_. You could do `Promise.resolve().then(() => { <your code> })` to force your code to run in a Promise task completion which would essentially enqueue the task.

Comment: so there is no other way except using `setTimeout`, or worker process?

Comment: Sorry, my edit came a bit later than your comment; see above. It still is not going to run the code in parallel, but it would break the work up into separate tasks so that high-priority tasks may interleave with your processing tasks. But I believe Promise tasks are pretty high-priority so you still may be robbing your UI thread if the tasks take up a lot of CPU.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about the [event loop phases](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) in the node.js documentation.

Comment: thanks, I understand now that code won't run in parallel unless it is in a separate thread. But it would give the browser some time to do other things in between. I think I will try to separate the code somehow and use web workers so the UI is not affected by other things